# Access Inner Class Method (from Viewholder in adapter) from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, methods, inner-classes

I have a fragment lets call it `EventFragment`, and I have an `RecyclerView.Adapter` called `EventAdapter`, inside that adapter is a viewholder class called `EventViewHolder`. I want access an animation method inside the viewholder class from the `Fragment`.

How would I accomplish this? I was thinking to define another interface to accomplish this.

This is what I have so far:

**OnAnimationListener**

```
public interface OnAnimationListener {
    void onAnimation();
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleView.ViewHolder> {

    // Boilerplate initialization stuff here

    public class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnAnimationListener {

        // Initialization code

        @Override
        public void onAnimation() {
            // Do an animation
        }

    }

}
```

**EventFragment**

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

   // Boilerplate initialization code

}
```

I am thinking I should implement an interface inside the `Fragment` like so:

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment implements onAnimationListener {

    private void initAdapter() {
        mAdapter.setOnAnimationListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimation(Data data) {
        // pass any data
    }

}
```

Then I'm sort of stuck at this point. Normally you would call this once the listener is passed through:

```
OnAnimationListener.onAnimation(...)
```

But this doesn't make sense. The code flow goes like this:

```
EventFragment --> Adapter --> ViewHolder
```

I need to implement the following code flow:

```
EventFragment (get access to specific viewholder and do animation) <--> Viewholder
```

How should I accomplish this? Maybe pass the interface from the Viewholder to the Fragment instead, and call `mOnAnimationListener.onAnimation()` from the fragment right?

I want to have specific control of when the animation occurs on the `EventViewHolder` and I want to have this control from the `EventFragment` how should I go about tackling this?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to animate the `RecyclerView`'s items you can take a look at `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator`.

If not (or if you still want to handle this in the fragment) you can attach click listeners for your views inside the `ViewHolder` object and handle the clicks by passing the event up `ViewHolder->Adapter->Fragment` via the mechanism you already have (and passing the view received in `onClick` as a parameter). Personally I'd stay away from this pattern. One reason being that the `RecyclerView` can be scrolled in the meantime and I don't have enough knowledge right now on what happens to that particular view once it's off position or maybe even off screen. Or maybe pointing to other data.